# FindControl does not work in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

void GridView1_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        (e.Row.FindControl("linkDocs") as HyperLink).Visible = false;


    }

}
```

I can't get that code sample to work.
I need to access a hyperlink control on my page.

I have a master page setup.

Comment: Is this hyperlink control in the gridview row, or elsewhere on the page itself?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using a TemplateField containing a Hyperlink with ID="linkDocs".

Maybe the OnRowDataBound Event is better suited for your needs.